# Use docker compose in run task on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm setting up data processing pipeline by using ECS and a couple of docker images that need to work together. To do so I have docker compose file prepared and the prepared docker images are available on ECR.
Now I'm trying to run a task on ECS instance, but that requires triggering docker compose that will run docker services in a correct order.

To do so, I have created container definitions and task definition, but how do I run a task to use docker compose? I'm thinking about using docker in docker as the only solution, but it would be very unclean.

I tried using `ecs-cli compose`, that would be exactly what I want. But it doesn't handle few options that I need (`depends_on`, `tty`, `volumes`). Also there is no programmatic SDK available for use.

Comment: If you need functionality that isn't supported by `ecs-cli compose`, you'll need to use the SDK to create ECS Task Definitions directly.